# How can I get the chosen Select Box's Labels from the main function using wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm sorry for my bad question.I struggled to post my source code because of indent errors.

1.My environment

Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct  6 2017, 12:04:38) 
  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] 
  on  darwin

2.Question

How can I get the chosen Select Box's Labels from the main function using wxPython? I made a program using wxPython as follows.I tried it again and again, but I couldn't.Please give your advise.

In the main() function as follows,

```
print("Main:", sf.getFruitsValue())
```

shows `NULL`. I would like to get the chosen Select Box's Labels. In the function `OnClick()` of the class

```
print("OnClick:", self.favorite_fruits)
```

can show the right chosen labels.

3.Source(Failure)

```
import os
import wx

class SelectFruits(wx.Frame):

    panel=''
    layout=''
    checkBox=[]
    favorite_fruits=[]

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(750, 500))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def setLayout(self,fruits):
        self.layout = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.showMsg1=wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'Choose the favorite fruits.')
        self.layout.Add(self.showMsg1, proportion=1)

        for index, target in enumerate(fruits):
            (self.checkBox).append(wx.CheckBox(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, target))
            self.layout.Add(self.checkBox[index], flag=wx.GROW)

        self.commit_button = wx.Button(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Commit")
        self.layout.Add(self.commit_button, proportion=1)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.layout)
        self.Refresh()
        self.commit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnClick)

    def OnClick(self,event):
        eventObj = event.GetEventObject()
        self.favorite_fruits = []
        for target in self.checkBox:
            if target.IsChecked():
                self.favorite_fruits.append(target.GetLabel())

        print("OnClick:",self.favorite_fruits)

    def getFruitsValue(self):
        return self.favorite_fruits

def main():
    fruits=["Apple","Banana","Grape","Kiwi","Mango","Orange","Pineapple","Strawberry"]
    app = wx.App(False)
    sf = SelectFruits(None, wx.ID_ANY, "FruitSelect")
    sf.setLayout(fruits)
    print("Main:",sf.getFruitsValue())
    app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You have posted the code for your question as an answer. Delete this answer and edit the question to include this code. To answer your question, you are already getting the answer which is [] i.e an empty list. That is because nothing has been selected YET, so self.favorite_fruits is EMPTY.

Comment: @HiroyasuTakeda Now that you've edited the question, it will be put into a queue for higher reputation users to review and possibly reopen. That queue currently has a couple hundred questions in it, so hopefully your question will be reviewed and reopened in the next 24 hours.

Comment: >you are already getting the answer which is [] i.e an empty list.That is because nothing has been selected YET

(My comment)
Thank you for your advices.
After I selected the checkbox, I could get the names of the selected labels in the function "OnClick()". But I could not get the names of the chosen labels in the main function.